# Disable Gerrit for repository in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, gerrit

I accidentally enabled Gerrit for one of my Git repositories when developing in Eclipse. Is there any way to disable this?

I'm primarily asking because it seems to have the side-effect of slowing down my staging processing within Eclipse for that repository ever since the enabling of Gerrit.

*Update:*
I couldn't find anything in the Git config for the repository that pointed to Gerrit or reviewing. So, I tried removing the repository and the projects associated with it from the workspace and then re-importing it, but that doesn't help either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that Gerrit is configured through the existing remote configuration (e.g., `origin`) itself. There are specific push/fetch specs associated with Gerrit that are added by Eclipse. If you simple remove all the existing specs and add the ones you need (or just `All Branches Spec`) from both the push and fetch spects, then Gerrit is disabled again.

Thanks to @VonC for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Nice feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: For me, it was caused by following setting in `.git/config` of the local repository: `fetch = refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*`

Answer (score 0):

Both "[Eclipse Gerrit](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Gerrit#Enabling_Gerrit_for_your_Eclipse.org_Project)" and "[EGit/Contributor Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide)" mentions a remote named "review"

Check in command line if you can remove it:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote remove review
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it from the command prompt, but kept getting `error: Could not remove config section 'remote.review'`